# How to find smallest cost of edges to add to a weighted graph to make it biconnected?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

This is related to the following problem- http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/contests/aug2005/Advanced-2.php . Any hints on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need a solution to the problem in the link or do you need the answer to the title of your question? The former is easier.

Comment: @ILoveCoding Isn't the problem in the link asking the same thing? If not, please provide the former.

Comment: The problem in the link is easier because it is guaranteed that all cities are connected to the capital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few simple observation that give us a solution to this problem:

1. If a non-capital city is removed, the rest of the graph is still connected. It is the case because we can reach one city from another through the capital.
2. If a capital is removed, the rest of the graph is empty.

It means that we just need to find a minimum spanning tree in the given graph after removing the first vertex and all edges adjacent to it. You can find a minimum spanning tree using any standard algorithm(for example, Prim's).

Comment: Thanx...Btw any idea regarding the answer to the question title?